# Laravel - API Versioning /v2/ endpoints always return 401

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport, api-versioning

I'm currently working on a Laravel API which uses Laravel Passport (OAuth2). I recently added a v2 to my Laravel application API. Everything works fine on my local machine. But on my TEST-Server, the application always throws a 401 when I send a request to a v2 endpoint.

Here is my setup:

RouteServiceProvider:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['api', 'api_version:v1'],
        'namespace'  => "{$this->namespace}",
        'prefix'     => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });    
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['api', 'api_version:v2'],
        'namespace'  => "{$this->namespace}\V2",
        'prefix'     => 'api/v2',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api/api_v2.php');
    });
}
```

auth.php:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api_v2' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users_v2',
    ],
],

// ...

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Base\User::class,
    ],
    'users_v2' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\V2\Base\User::class,
    ],
],
```

routes/api_v2.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api_v2']], function() {
    Route::get('user', 'Base\UserController@authUserV2');
    // ...
});
```

APIVersion Middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $guard)
{
    if ($guard != 'v1') {
        // Morph user model
        $apiVersion = $guard == '' ? '' : ('\\' . strtoupper($guard) . '\\');
        Relation::morphMap([
            'App\User' => 'App\Models\Base\User',
            'App\Models\Base\User' => 'App\Models' . $apiVersion . 'Base\User'
        ]);

    config(['app.api.version' => $guard]);
    return $next($request);
}
```

The request throws a 401 before the APIVersion middleware is executed.

I don't know why it works on my local machine, but not on my Test server. Is this error code or machine related?

### Edit

I found out, that as soon as I change the guard of api_v2 back to `users` instead of `users_v2` It works. But then it does not use the V2 User Model, which of course throws errors in my Controllers.

Comment: is there any specific reason to have created another guard for the v2 ?

Comment: I have a new User model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **hours** of searching, I found my problem.
The database of my local machine has an older `oauth_clients` table, which doesn't contain the `provider` column. After changing the `provider` column on my Test Server to `NULL`, everything is working fine!

Does someone know if it is possible to specify multiple providers in this column instead of allowing all?